# Verifying Multiple users on a Simple Login System

Tags: java, authentication

Im using .txt file as a database and there are 2 users in this file but this code can read only 1 user and the other cannot. im trying that the both of users will work

```
  try {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\KIDS\\Desktop\\Marvels\\LoginCred\\Employeelogin.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
  //      READS THE TEXT
  String usernameholder = br.readLine().substring(9);
  String passwordholder = br.readLine().substring(9);
 if(usernameid.getText().equals(usernameholder)&& passwordid.getText().equals(passwordholder)) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Access Granted!");
 }
 else{
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Username/Password");
 }
}
catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error");
}
```

Here is the Users
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl4P6.png)

Comment: How do you expect this to work? You're only reading the first two lines of the file.

Comment: using for loop may help?